# Defining binary operations of isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question given is:

**The map $f : \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z$ defined by $f(n) = n + 1$ for $n \in \Bbb Z$ is one to one and onto Z. Give the definition of a
binary operation $*$ on $\Bbb Z$ such that $f$ is an isomorphism mapping $(\Bbb Z, +)$ onto $(\Bbb Z, * )$.**

So I know this means I need to equate $f(a + b) = f(a) * f(b)$ with a defined $*$ of my choosing.

If I define $f(a) * f(b)$ as $f(a) + f(b) - 1$ is this an acceptable definition?

Because then $f(a+b) = (a+b) + 1$ and $f(a) * f(b) = (a+1) + (b + 1) - 1 = (a + b) + 1$, and the identity element would be $1$ since $f(0) = 1$?

Comment: The question is not completely clear: it says "isomorphism mapping $(\mathbb Z, \cdot)$", etc. Now, "isomorphism" always refers to a specific algebraic structure (monoids, groups, rings, etc). But what type of structure is referred to here? $(\mathbb Z, \cdot)$ seems to indicate the set $\mathbb Z$ with the product, *not* the sum as you have assumed in your answer, and which is a monoid but not a group.

Comment: I fixed the "dot" to a +.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $G$ is group, and $S$ is a set and $f:G \longrightarrow S$ is a bijection, one can define a group stucture on $S$ such that $f$ is an isomorphism:

For any $x,y \in S$, define $x \cdot y = f(f^{-1}(x) \cdot f^{-1}(y))$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is okay as long as the isomorphism is to be understood as an isomorphism of *monoids*: $(\mathbb Z, +)\rightarrow (\mathbb Z, *)$. The text is not precise because it doesn't say "isomorphism" to which algebraic structure is referred here. "Isomorphism" is always relative to the type of algebraic structure involved. If in your problem it means a group isomorphism, you must prove that you also have $f(-a)=f(a)^{-1}$, i.e. the inverse is preserved as well.

Comment: I mistakenly added "dot" instead of +, I fixed it in the question a few minutes ago.

Comment: @OliverG I see, but the question I pose is still valid, do you see why?

Comment: I haven't come across the term "monoid", but the rest makes sense.